# How to add preserveSymlinks Angular build option based on enviroment

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How can I set a build option, `preserveSymlinks` in angular.json based on the environment? 
I mean if the environment is prod the option must be `true`, if not it must be `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular.json has the configuration for production to set `preserveSymlinks`:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
        "fileReplacements": [ {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
        ],
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "budgets": [ {
            "type": "initial", "maximumWarning": "2mb", "maximumError": "5mb"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

By default `preserveSymlinks` is false. You don't need to put it for `dev` environment.

Comment: but if the key is nested do I have to put all the path?

Comment: @ALopez Can you give us an example of what you want to put?

Comment: preserveSymlinks that is inside build options

Comment: @ALopez you add it this way `"preserveSymlinks": true`. I also added it in the above answer/ configuration.